# Idioms in Nebensatz: Should I change the structure of the idiom?

Tags: idiom, subordinate-clause

Take for example the idiom:

> Das ist mir Wurst

If I put such an idiom in the `Nebensatz`, should I change the structure of the idiom? Which of the following is correct?

> Ich kenne das nicht, weil *das ist mir Wurst*.

or

> Ich kenne das nicht, weil *das mir Wurst ist*.

Answer (score 4):

A Nebensatz has the finite verb in final position, so the first example is wrong and the second would be correct.

That being said, the following structure feels most natural to me:

> Ich kenne das nicht, weil mir das Wurst ist.

Comment: I can't help but find the second example worse. The OP is aware of the standard syntax, so what is your contribution? Are you arguimg a sentence containing *is mir wurscht* had to conform with High German standard orthography?

Comment: Ich hab keine Ahnung, was du sagen möchtest.

Comment: Danke für die Nachfrage. Ich meinte, "das ist mir wurst" sei keine Rechtfertigung für "ich habe keine Ahnung". Es ist nichtmal eine Begründung, insofern die Idiome um "is egal" eher imperativen Charakter haben. Soweit wäre es durchaus sinnvoll eben keinen Nebensatz zu formulieren, weil: Das ist mir Wurst. Immerhin ist diese Konstruktion historisch belegt und tritt neuerdings auch wieder vermehrt auf (gab hier bereits Fragen dazu). So oder stellt sich die Frage nach dem Bezugspunkt für "das". Deine Lesart suggeriert das Ahnen als Bezug. Das wäre aber falsch. Zwei Hauptsätze wären wohl besser.

Comment: Ob der Satz inhaltlich sinnvoll ist, spielt bei einer Grammatikfrage erstmal keine Rolle. `Das ist mir Wurst` ist auch nur umgangssprachlich für das ist mir egal oder das interessiert mich nicht. Und die Begründung, dass ich etwas nicht kenne, weil es mich nicht interessiert, halte ich für plausibel.

Comment: Das kannst du halten wie du willst, aber plausibel ist es streng genommen nicht, von etwas, über das man nichts weiß, zu wissen, dass es einen nicht interessiert. Allerdings habe ich total übersehen, dass OP die Standardsyntax gar nicht kennt. Nix für ungut.

Comment: @vectory was ich für plausibel erachte und was nicht, kannst du doch gar nicht beurteilen. Ich gehe auch immer vom umgangssprachlichen Fall aus, da die meisten Leute so kommunizieren und es sicht um eine Debatte von Sprach- und Pedantikfetischisten handelt. Und wenn mich jemand fragt, ob ich das neue deutsche Promisternchenpärchen kenne, würde ich tatsächlich wörtlich so antworten, wie es oben in der eingefärbten Box steht.

Comment: "*kannst du doch gar nicht beurteilen.*", ja, aber nicht etwa weil es mich nicht interessiert ;)